# Formula to find item from a list that has total price then cross reference the different lists that contain that item to find the value of item?

Tags: excel, list, math, formula

row example-
lets say in column one I have apple|banana|pear
column 2 is number of items in column 1 (3)
column 3 is total price of all 3 items (42)
so I know apple+banana+pear=42
Now throughout column 1 I have a bunch of variations of items with varrying amounts of 1-6 items(4 items apple|banana|pear|egg, etc.)
I could go through and filter the column for lists that contain lets say apples and find each price manually but I'm wondering if there is a formula that could complete this task automatically.
So in column 6-11 I would split the items so each has its own cell then in 12-17 I would run the formula to find the price of each item.
So for example it would look like

| 1                   |2    | 3  | 4    | 5      | 6    | 7    | 8   | 9 |
| apple|banana|pear   |    3| 42 |apple | banana | pear |  14  | 16  | 12|

So far all I have done is split each list into their own cells, and wrote a formula to figure out how many items in each list. I don't really know how to figure this out without AI or if its even possible on excel. I guess maybe vlookup a value and divide total by number of containers then average because I have about 1000 rows of lists so maybe it will give me the best estimate?

Comment: Vlookup(), xlookup() or index() with match(). So many examples on here.

Comment: the price of each item isn't written anywhere, I have to find out how much of the total an item is. so lets say 3 items cost 42, I'm not told what each item costs by itself but I know all 3 together sum to 42 so it could be any combination of prices.